# How to read grouped output and break?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig output file whose raw data looks likes this (2 fields):

```
(45578713,45578728,)    8139
```

The first field is a group field from previous pig job (which I can't change).

Now I need to read this and I want to break the first field - (45578713,45578728,) - into individual numbers like the following (so total 3 fields)

```
45578713        45578728        8139
```

How can I do this? I tried to use Pig streaming but I feel like there must be something I can do from Pig directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you.

`m = FOREACH g GENERATE FLATTEN(group), number;`

Take a look at [`FLATTEN`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html) operator.